# PHP Soap wsdl response Issue

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I am working on php soap to implement an insurance policy issuing application.Everything i set and i get a response number from web service.But i dont know how to fetch the response data from web service (xml).Below i am providing my web service request and response.

Link to web service
https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?op=CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy

this is the code i am trying..please guide me.

```
class SOAPStruct
{
    function __construct($user, $pass) 
    {
        $this->userName = $user;
        $this->Password = $pass;
    }
}

$service = new SoapClient("https://es.adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServicesNew.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

$auth = new SOAPStruct('*****','****');

$header = new SoapHeader("http://adpolice.gov.ae/TrafficInsurance/TrafficInsuranceServices.asmx",'SoapHeaderIn',$auth,false); 

$service->__setSoapHeaders(array($header)); 

$param = array('lngInsuranceCompanyCode'=> '1','intInsuranceKindCode'=>'1','lngTcf'=>'1','strPolicyNo'=>'1','dtExpiryDate'=>'2016-04-30','dtStartDate'=>'2015-03-31','strChassisNo'=>'6T1BE4DFDFDFDFD','strRemarks'=>'dfdf','strUserCreated'=>'dfdfd');

$response = $service->CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy($param);
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is

```
$xml =  $service->__getLastResponse();
print_r($xml);
```